# How to verify if application has done createForm statement?

Tags: delphi

In `DPR` file:

```
Application.CreateForm(TMain, Main);
Application.CreateForm(TCommStatus, CommStatus);
```

But I get an error if I want to use CommStatus in Main, because it was not instanced yet. Then inside TMain I tried:

```
procedure TMainWindow.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TCommStatus, CommStatus);
  CommStatus.Expand(Self);
end;
```

I was trying to have my LOG window to be positioned and sized according to my MainWindow position and width. But as my LOG window is created after Main Window, I can't really call it in OnCreate(), even because there is no correct positioning data in OnCreate().

Comment: Please specify if `VCL` or `FMX`

Comment: Are you sure that's the 'expand' code? If so you're getting the position of the CommStatus form itself, you can't have a 'Self' as a variable in a method.

Comment: I think you reasoning that leads to using a global variable is erroneous. Use can use a member field. If some other party needs it, pass it to that other party as a parameter. Globals are to be avoided.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan actually I was trying to have my LOG window to be positioned and sized according to my MainWindow position and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Application.CreateForm` to create the CommStatus form at all. Create it yourself in your `MainWindow.OnCreate`:

```
proccedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CommStatus := TCommStatus.Create(Self);
  CommStatus.Expand(Self);
end;
```

Don't forget to remove `CommStatus` from the auto-create forms list (in Project->Options->Forms).

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know if CommStatus is Assigned before execute CreateForm.

You answered your own question - use `Assigned()`, eg:

```
uses
  ..., CommStatusFormUnit;

if not Assigned(CommStatus) then
  Application.CreateForm(TCommStatus, CommStatus);
```

Or:

```
uses
  ..., CommStatusFormUnit;

if not Assigned(CommStatus) then
  CommStatus := TCommStatus.Create(Application);
```

Global variables, like the `CommStatus` variable in the `CommStatusFormUnit` unit, are zero-initialized at program startup, thus `Assinged()` will return False until the form is actually created, as long as you assign the new Form instance to the global variable (as the examples above do).

> But CommStatus identifier does not exists until it. So I can't use Assigned(CommStatus).

Yes, it does exist, and yes, you can use `Assigned(CommStatus)`.  If you are having errors with it, then you are not using it correctly.

> Expand(Self) should use Main position information to put CommStatus beside Main in the same left position, but it doesn't.

Then you are not handling the positioning logic correctly.

Comment: 1st done by this answer. the 2nd I had to set position in the Main form.

Comment: When using `FMX` this can lead to some unwanted behaviour. `Application.CreateForm( TForm1, Form1 );` did **not** set `Form1` to a valid instance immediately. This is done when the framework is fully loaded. On startup you cannot rely on `Assigned( Form1 )` to know if the form was already created or not.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create `CommStatus` first in your `DPR`. But without using `Application.CreateFom` (which would then incorrectly make `CommStatus` you main form).
This way you'll know it has definitely been created, and not have to worry.

I.e.

```
CommStatus := TCommStatus.Create(Application);
Application.CreateForm(TMain, Main);
```

However, that fact that you're trying to Expand CommStatus in the `OnShow` of your main form seems a little dubious to me. You've created a hidden dependency between the two forms, which is exactly one of the reasons globals are frowned upon.

One option to clean that up would be as follows:

```
CommStatus := TCommStatus.Create(Application);
Application.CreateForm(TMain, Main);
CommStatus.Expand(Main);
```

This way the relationship between the two is explicit and less error-prone.